# neural network software

Tags: neural-network

hi 
i neeeeed a software for use in learning neural network?
i use matlab now.i like to see layers, nerons,bayases,outpots and work with them? what is the best one?

Comment: I guess Matlab is the best one

Comment: i need it to be grafical

Answer (score 1):

If you implement [FANN](http://leenissen.dk/fann/), you can use the [FANN Explorer](http://leenissen.dk/fann/gui.php) to visualise your network as you train/test it, before full implementation.